# Multiple order objects - php

Tags: php

Supposing you have an object:

```
$arr = array(
   array('name' => 'toto', 'firstname' => 'abc'),
   array('name' => 'toto2', 'firstname' => 'aaa')
);
```

I want to order it by name AND firstname. You cannot use keyword "use" for old version of php like 5.2. If a general function is not possible, then build a function for this specific case.

Thanks.

Comment: how to to do sorts has been answered multiple times before. See the related section to the right please. Also, StackOverflow is not a site to request people to write code for you.

Answer (score 0):

Use usort with a callback that compares the elements of the array according to the rules you specify in the callback.